# which one is faster binarysearch or indexof?

Tags: c#, performance, arraylist, binary-search, indexof

I have a very big ArrayList of string in C#, and periodically I'm searching for a string in this ArrayList. Which one is faster , using `ArrayList.IndexOf()` or `ArrayList.BinarySearch()`? I can sort the ArrayList.

Comment: Have you got any preliminary performance measurements ?

Comment: Read the legendary [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: How many times will you search in the list?

Comment: What about using other data structures like HashSet? ( **O(1)** )

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The arraylist is full of strings, millions basically. I have already used hashtable to sort the elements and use key,value pairs. But still the value of each key is an arraylist and still I have to search for a specific element in the arraylist. I'm searching for the elements many many times since it is like a method for checking if the element is avaialble in the list or not.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation explains everything for you.

From [ArrayList.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tzt7yz3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The elements of the ArrayList **must already be sorted** in increasing
>   value according to the sort order defined by the IComparable
>   implementation; otherwise, the result might be incorrect.
>
> This method is an **O(log n)** operation, where n is Count.

From [ArrayList.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w3e62a8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an
>   **O(n)** operation, where n is Count.

Comment: probably the BinarySearch is better in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Few years later, see the results and the functions below, looks like IndexOf is much quicker in sorted array unless I've done something wrong.

```
|                  Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Rank | Allocated |
|------------------------ |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-----:|----------:|
|            ArrayIndexOf |   4.451 ns | 0.0720 ns | 0.0638 ns |    1 |         - |
|       ArrayBinarySearch |  11.062 ns | 0.1574 ns | 0.1314 ns |    2 |         - |
|      ArrayIndexOfString |  53.150 ns | 0.6027 ns | 0.5343 ns |    3 |         - |
| ArrayBinarySearchString | 170.023 ns | 1.9789 ns | 1.6524 ns |    4 |         - |




private string[] strings = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
private int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

[Benchmark]
public int ArrayBinarySearch()
{
    var x = Array.BinarySearch(nums, 9);
    return x < 0 ? -1 : x;
}

[Benchmark]
public int ArrayIndexOf()
{
    return Array.IndexOf(nums, 9);
}

[Benchmark]
public int ArrayBinarySearchString()
{
    var x = Array.BinarySearch(strings, "j");
    return x < 0 ? -1 : x;
}

[Benchmark]
public int ArrayIndexOfString()
{
    return Array.IndexOf(strings, "j");
}
```

Comment: Try also with longer arrays, for example with 100 or 1000 elements, and you might get different results. Also searching always for the last element in the list makes for a non representative benchmark. You need to search for elements in various positions, and also for non-existent elements.

Comment: I did search for non-last but as the IndexOf was in this small array fastest I went for the worse scenario -> the last element to make the IndexOf slowest possible. ps. I will go with longer test as well as this is interesting

Comment: *"Looks like IndexOf is much quicker..."* -- You proved that it's much quicker, provided that the array has 10 elements and you are searching for the 10nth element. You didn't prove anything else, and your generalized conclusion is misleading. So I'll have to downvote for now. I might change my vote when the answer is updated with a more narrow conclusion, or a more wide benchmark.